# If using a for loop in a timer tick event, will the for "test for" every tick, or all at once, as regular?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How will a for loop operate inside a timer tick event?

Comment: Whatever code is in the Tick event will run each time the event fires.  Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: The loop will block the UI until it has completed its iteration. Then when the UI is unblocked again the same will happen on the next tick.